# Custom Payment Method in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, payment-methods, captcha, authorize

I am working on implementing a new **payment module** using **Magento 2.1.6** and want to understand the core concept behind this logic. I know I have to extend from Payment_Model_AbstractMethod or any of its children classes, but my problem is How does the payment module flow work (which functions are called specifically when pressing checkout and place order buttons). When to use and how to use capture and authorize methods in my model.
Finally, how can i check the transaction status is it failed or success?

Answer (score 1):

When **place order** button press from checkout. It's call following class

```
//Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

Then

```
$orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
```

Now open **Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php**
look **placeOrder** method. Now look following method in same class.

```
protected function submitQuote(QuoteEntity $quote, $orderData = [])
{
    .......
    $order = $this->orderManagement->place($order);
}
```

Now open **Magento/Sales/Model/Service/OrderService.php**
**place** method.

Now open **Magento/Sales/Model/Order.php**

```
/**
 * Place order
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function place()
{
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_before', ['order' => $this]);
    $this->_placePayment();
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_after', ['order' => $this]);
    return $this;
}

/**
     * Place order payments
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _placePayment()
    {
        $this->getPayment()->place();
        return $this;
    }
```

Look **$this->getPayment()->place();** this is the main method who is responsible for payment.

Now open **Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php**

[This line return actual payment method class object](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php#L325)

[Check this line here call actual class method](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php#L416)